# Eclipse: infinitest vs. JUnit: character encoding

Tags: eclipse, unicode, junit, infinitest

I'm using infinitest in Eclipse and I have a strange phenomenon in connection with JUnit.

I have code that uses `org.apache.http.HttpResponse.getEntity()` and `org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity`. The JUnit test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void convertEncodedContentToString() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  HttpResponse httpResponseMock = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);

  Mockito.when(httpResponseMock.getEntity()).thenReturn(new StringEntity("huiäöüß@€", HTTP.UTF_8));
  Assert.assertEquals("huiäöüß@€", parser.convertContentToString(httpResponseMock));
}
```

All source files are stored in UTF-8.

If I let JUnit execute this method, it works fine.

However, if infinitest runs this test it complains that the assertion fails.

```
ComparisonFailure (expected:<hui[äöüß@€]> but was:<hui[Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃŸ@â‚¬]>) in ResponseBodyParserFactoryTest.convertEncodedContentToString
```

Obviously there is a character encoding problem.

As infinitest has close to no options I have no idea how to help infinitest to run this test properly. Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: You might want to look at [Infinitest's issue tracker](https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues) and see if someone has reported a similar issue before, then post it yourself if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to say to infinitest that it must use the UTF-8 charset to run the tests.

Just add a file in your Eclipse project: "infinitest.args".
In this file, add the following:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

And so, inifinitest will use UTF-8

User guide: http://infinitest.github.com/doc/user_guide.html specifically the 'Setting JVM Options' section